# Adhkar question

Tags: dhikr, mustahab

AOA

I just want to ask the following please:

1. Is reciting "Ya Hayyu Ya Qayyumu be rahmatika astaghis", "La haula wala quwatta Illah billah", "HAsbunallahu wa nayma mal wakeel", "La illaha Illa anta Subhanka Inni kuntu minzalimeen", "Allaho Allaho rabbi la ushriko bihi shayia" are all mustahab adhkar or any is fard also.
2. If I recite any one or two of the above-mentioned adhkar so is it ok or I have to recite all of them.

Please answer me I am really worried.

Answer (score 1):

Adhkar and tasbeeh are not obligatory or fard. The only obligatory worship is Salat, Fasting and Hajj. Every other way of worship is Nafali, and helps us thank Allah, remember Him, and gain also rewards. Skipping them would not make us sinful, but it is better to perform Adhkar as much as we can.

> “and remember Allah much, that you may be successful”
>
> [al-Jumu‘ah 62:10].

الله اعلم